# What drivers do I need to make the special keys on my old Fellowes Microban keyboard work?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, keyboard

I have a Fellowes Microban Slimline Standard Antimicrobial Keyboard KU-0420 at home and at work. At home it works with Windows 10, including the special keys like volume, forward, and back. But at work (also Windows 10) only the regular keys work. I asked tech support and they said the drivers don't exist anymore. This is true, I contacted Fellowes and they said the keyboard doesn't work with Windows 10. But clearly I have the drivers for them on my home Windows 10 computer somehow. Are there drivers for another keyboard that would work with this one, which I could get tech support to install? Oh, also I know it is not a problem with my work keyboard, because it works with my home computer.

(https://www.nix.ru/autocatalog/keyboards_chicony/Klaviatura-Chicony-KU-0420-Black-Silver-USB-104KL-plus-17KL-M-Med_103151.html)

Comment: Do you have a different version of Windows? e.g Home at home and Enterprise at Work?

Comment: I have Home at home, I'm assuming I have some kind of Enterprise at work but I'll have to check.

Comment: Yes I have Windows 10 Enterprise at work.

Comment: It is possible that Windows 10 Enterprise (business system) does not support the keyboard.